# Get max value based on condition

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, max

I'm trying to get the max noteId for each project but return notes that have been pinned first and not return notes that are not pinned within the same project.

```
select refId as projectId, max(noteId) as noteId
    from notes 
    where noteType='project' 
    and ((noteCat='critical project' and pinned=1) or noteCat='critical 
project') 
    group by refId, pinned
    order by pinned desc
```

Sample Data:

```
|---------|-----------|--------------|------------------|----------|
| noteId  | projectId |   noteType   |      noteCat     |  pinned  |
|---------|-----------|--------------|------------------|----------|
| 306586  |   34256   |   project    | critical project |     1    |
|---------|-----------|--------------|------------------|----------|
| 298183  |    972    |   project    | critical project |     0    |
|---------|-----------|--------------|------------------|----------|
| 296114  |   32549   |   project    | critical project |     0    |
|---------|-----------|--------------|------------------|----------|
| 295668  |    972    |   project    | critical project |     0    |
|---------|-----------|--------------|------------------|----------|
| 295463  |    972    |   project    | critical project |     1    |
|---------|-----------|--------------|------------------|----------|
```

Expected results should be:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Project Id     |      Note Id     |       Pinned     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          972        |       295463     |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         34256       |       306586     |         0        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         32549       |       296114     |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Actual results are:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Project Id     |      Note Id     |       Pinned     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          972        |       295463     |         1        | -- Older noteId but pinned.
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         34256       |       306586     |         0        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          972        |       298183     |         0        | --This should not be returned.
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         32549       |       296114     |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: *Only showing pinned column for the example.

Comment: You forgot to post input sample data.

Comment: @stickybit I have now added the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the `row_number()` window function to generate a row number per project putting pinned before unpinned notes an higher IDs before lower ones.

```
SELECT x.projectid,
       x.noteid,
       x.pinned
       FROM (SELECT n.projectid,
                    n.noteid,
                    n.pinned,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY n.projectid
                                       ORDER BY n.pinned DESC,
                                                n.noteid DESC) rn
                    FROM notes n) x
       WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @stickybit however when I run the query on my data no unpinned items are returned.